# What is the Point Spread Function of a pinhole camera?

Tags: optics, vectors, linear-algebra, camera, imaging

Is the geometric spread of a pinhole camera a uniform blur convolution?

Pinhole cameras have blur due to a. wave effects (diffraction) and b. ray effects (geometric properties).  This question ignores a and considers b only.

Pinhole cameras spread points to a region on the image plane.  Is it correct that this spread is *uniform*, that is, modeled by a uniform blur convolution kernel: each point spreads evenly to a disc, with the same intensity at each point of the disc.  (This is different than the more typical Gaussian blur which is caused by other effects.)

Mathematical analysis below.  Can you please confirm or refute it?

Let $\delta = - \frac {d_s}{f}$, where $d_s$ is the distance from aperture to subject, and $f$ the distance from aperture to image plane (i.e. the focal length).  Let $\vec s$ be the $(x,y)$ coordinates of a point on the subject plane.  For an aperture with radius close to zero, the image on the image plane will be the dilation by $\delta$, so $$\vec i_{a_0} = \delta \vec s.$$

For an aperture with radius greater than zero, we can look at the contribution of each small region of the aperture individually.  Let $\vec a_n$ be the coordinates on the aperture plane of a portion of the aperture.  The resultant image on the image plane is a dilation with center $\vec a_n$ by $\delta$, so $$\vec i_{\vec a_n} = \delta(\vec s - \vec a_n) + \vec a_n \\ \vec i_{\vec a_n} = \delta\vec s + (1 - \delta)\vec a_n$$ which means that each resulting contribution is the original image, dilated by a constant, and translated in direct proportion to the corresponding distance from the center of the aperture.  These contributions combine to form a uniform blur with kernel radius equal to $(1 - \delta)r_a$, where $r_a$ is the radius of the aperture.

Is this correct? Is there a source where this is derived?